# Providing generic interface with TMP and SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

At the moment, I have the below working code where using class `X`, I provide a generic interface for multiple classes - I only expect a static `f` function to be present, but neither do I fix the return type nor the parameters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {
public:
  static void f()
  {
    std::cout << "A::f()" << std::endl;
  }
};

class B {
public:
  static size_t f(std::string const& s_)
  {
    std::cout << "B::f()" << std::endl;
    return s_.size();
  }
};

class C {
};


template <typename T>
class X {
public:
  static
  void
  f(...)
  {
    std::cout << "Operation not supported!" << std::endl;
  }

  template <typename... Args>
  static
  std::result_of_t<decltype(&T::f)(Args...)>
  f(Args&&... args_)
  {
    return T::f(std::forward<Args>(args_)...);
  }
};

int main()
{
  X<A>::f();  // Compiles, but unexpected overload!
  auto const x = X<B>::f("Hello");  // Works just fine
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
//  X<C>::f();  // Does NOT compile!
  return 0;
}
```

However, I've got multiple problems with it (as marked above in the comments):

1. If I allow the function to be not present and uncomment the line
   using `C` as a template parameter, the code does not compile, it
   still expects `C` to have a function `f`:

   ```
   In instantiation of ‘class X<C>’:
   required from here
   error: ‘f’ is not a member of ‘C’
   std::result_of_t<decltype(&T::f)(Args...)>
   ```

   Based on [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), I expected the ellipsis parameter do the trick.
2. On the other hand, even if this worked, I would have another problem: though `A` provides `f`, the overload with
   the ellipsis parameter is picked during overload resolution - where, of course, `f` provided by `A` is preferred.

(Used compiler: g++ (Ubuntu 8.1.0-5ubuntu1~16.04) 8.1.0; used standard: C++14.)

Any help solving the above problems (preferably both, at the same time) is welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose the following `X` struct

```
template <typename T>
struct X
 {
  static void g (...)
   { std::cout << "Operation not supported!" << std::endl; }

  template <typename ... As, typename U = T>
  static auto g(int, As && ... as)
     -> decltype( U::f(std::forward<As>(as)...) )
   { return T::f(std::forward<As>(as)...); }

  template <typename ... As>
  static auto f (As && ... as)
   { return g(0, std::forward<As>(as)...); }
 };
```

The points are

(1) Passing through a `g()` function with an additional unused parameter (`int` in the variadic version, adsorbed by `...` in the "not supported version"), permit to select the variadic version (called with `0` that is an `int`), when `sizeof...(As) == 0` and both `g()` functions are available. This because `int` is a better match (in an exact match) for `int` as `...`. But when the variadic version isn't available (see point (2)), the "non supported" version is still available (the only one available) and selected

(2) You have to SFINAE enable/disable the variadic version according the fact that the `f()` static method is (or ins't) available in `T`. Unfortunately `T` is a template argument of the class, not of the `g()` static method, so you can use it for SFINAE. The trick is SFINAE operate over an additional template parameter, `U`, that is defaulted to `T`

```
// ------------------------VVVVVVVVVVVVVV  additional U (defaulted to T) template type
template <typename ... As, typename U = T>
static auto g(int, As && ... as)
   -> decltype( U::f(std::forward<As>(as)...) )
// -------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//
// SFINAE enable this g() if (and only if) the call
//   U::f(std::forward<As>(as)...) is valid
```

The following is a simplified working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A
 { static void f() { std::cout << "A::f()" << std::endl; } };

struct B
 {
  static size_t f(std::string const& s_)
   { std::cout << "B::f()" << std::endl; return s_.size(); }
 };

struct C
 { };


template <typename T>
struct X
 {
  static void g (...)
   { std::cout << "Operation not supported!" << std::endl; }

  template <typename ... As, typename U = T>
  static auto g(int, As && ... as)
     -> decltype( U::f(std::forward<As>(as)...) )
   { return T::f(std::forward<As>(as)...); }

  template <typename ... As>
  static auto f (As && ... as)
   { return g(0, std::forward<As>(as)...); }
 };

int main ()
 {
   X<A>::f();  // now call variadic version
   auto const x = X<B>::f("Hello");  // Works just fine as before
   std::cout << x << std::endl;
   X<C>::f();  // now compile
 }
```